# error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef signed char int8_t’

Tags: c++, c

how can i solve this

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include/stdint.h:9,
             from /usr/include/inttypes.h:37,
             from /usr/include/stdio.h:44,
             from kernel.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdint.h:122:59: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef signed char 
int8_t’
typedef signed int int8_t __attribute__((__mode__(__QI__)));
                                                       ^
In file included from kernel.cpp:1:
includes/types.h:4:18: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef char int8_t’
 typedef char int8_t;
              ^~~~~~
```

i using linux mint xfce
I'm using G++ compilers, when I include the <stdio.h> library in my code, it gives this error

Comment: Do you get that if you ONLY `#include <stdio.h>` ? I.e. if you do not include anything else. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Your typedef in `includes/types.h` conflicts with a standard type name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i solve this

Remove the line:

```
typedef char int8_t;
```

From the file `includes/types.h`. Or do not include `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1):

That’s tough. You have two header files with different typedef’s for int8_t, so the compiler is quite right to complain, which doesn’t help you much :-(

The solution is not to include one of the files. Examine why types.h and stdint.h define int8_t at all, and why in this way. Examine why you include both stdio.h and types.h. What happens if you remove one include?

Answer (score 0):

C standard already adds `int8_t` in stdint.h. However it requires to define INT8_MAX macro in such a case. Just wrap your typedef with this macro

```c
#ifndef INT8_MAX
typedef ...
#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the other file is included first (which is actually the case here). Better to just remove the typedef and include `<stdint.h>` explicitly.

Comment: Check in both files if they use different names for this macro. Obviously #define INT8_MAX inside the #ifndef.